# Is there a way to define different dependencies for each project in a same Xcode workspace?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dependencies, cocoapods

I am trying to create a Xcode workspace which has multiple projects in it. I want to add different dependencies for each project. Let's say I have MyApp (Master project), WebService (framework) and UIComponent (framework) projects. I wan't to add Alamofire only to WebService project or I wan't to add Lottie for only to UIComponent project.

```
MyWorkspace
 |- MyApp
 |- WebService
    |-> Alamofire
 |- UIComponent
    |-> Lottie
```

The problem is, when I add WebService and UIComponent dependency to my MyApp project (via Linking Binaries from Xcode), it can access dependencies of my sub-projects. In other words MyApp project can access and import Alamofire and Lottie. Is there a way to prevent MyApp project can not import sub-projects dependencies?

I tried to achieve this using both Swift Package Manager and CocoaPods but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

## With Swift Package Manager

You actually don't need a workspace to do this. You could just use an Xcode Project. I am currently doing this for a project I'm working on.

```
RootProjectFolder
 - Core // Swift Package
 - DataAccess // Swift Package
 - Http // Swift Package
 - ApplicationServices // Swift Package
 - Presenters // Swift Package
 - App/
 - AppTests/
 - App.xcodeproj
```

Core is used in every package, Http in DataAccess, DataAccess in ApplicationServices, ApplicationServices in Presenters, and Presenters in the app.

To create a setup like this, open your workspace or Xcode project click file and create a new swift package. Save that package in your application's directory and link it to the project or workspace you want to work in.

[image: Swift package creation]

If you do this a few times you can start referencing the other local swift packages like this:

```swift
let package = Package(
    name: "ApplicationServices",
    products: [.library(
            name: "ApplicationServices",
            targets: ["ApplicationServices"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // NOTE that we can use a relative path to link  
        // to include the other local packages. 
        .package(name: "DataAccess", path: "../DataAccess"),
        .package(name: "Core", path: "../Core"),
        // Or the traditional way of pulling down a remote package
        .package(url: "https://github.com/some-swift/testing-package", .upToNextMajor(from: "9.0.0"))

    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "ApplicationServices",
            // This is where you tell the swift package to use a dependency
            dependencies: ["DataAccess", "Core"]), the
        .testTarget(
            name: "ApplicationServicesTests",
            dependencies: ["ApplicationServices", "DataAccess", "Core", "TestingPackage"]),
    ]
)
```

Then with a local package, we include it a little differently than a remote swift package. Click on the Project in the file navigation, select the app target, then under General in Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content click the `+` button. You should be able to select the local packages you care about.

If you need anything described more clearly let me know.

[image: Adding local packages]

Answer (score 0):

CocoaPods is fine, distinguish different target

```
#targetA: [AFNetworking,Masonry]
#targetB:[AFNetworking,SDWebImage]
abstract_target 'abstract_pod' do 
    pod 'AFNetworking'
    
    target 'targetA' do
        pod 'Masonry' 
    end
    
    target 'targetB' do
        pod 'SDWebImage' :path =>'./SDWebImage'
    end
end
```